USB webcam with light, microphone and speakers
I can find USB webcams with speakers and microphone OR with light and microphone. But I'm struggling to find one with all the three features.
I'm wondering why since usually, on a desktop PC, you need them all in order to make a clear videocall. Is there anything suitable on the market or I need to buy at least two different products?

That's basically a CCTV camera you're looking for. There is little reason for a webcam to have a spot light. Most can operate under low light conditions and will have light from a laptop or desktop screen, to boot. Also, the microphone and speakers tend to be functional at best.
But it may be easier for you to get a cheap phone and use it as a webcam instead. There are programs like https://alfred.camera/ that can do that. Plenty of others can do the same.
